# Запускаю бота для дискорда через cmd ошибки никакой нету, но бот не запускается в дискорде

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

вот код:

```
import discord

import config

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!' .format(self.user))

        async def on_message(self, message):
            print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}' .format(message))

            client = MyClient()
            client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: @Denis640Kb спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Ясно дело, вы ведь не создали объект вашего класса.

Answer (score 0):

Кажется, с вложенностью фигня. Подозреваю, что должно быть так:

```
import discord

import config

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!' .format(self.user))

    async def on_message(self, message):
        print('Message from {0.author}: {0.content}' .format(message))

client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```